# How to get variable out of JSON Url

Tags: jquery, json

I have problems getting a certain variable out of a URL variable.
The URL is:

```
.com/?asset=[{"AssetId":524,"DerivativeDefinitionId":6,"DerivativeId":816,"FileSizeInBytes":57131}]
```

I use the following code to get the asset part from the URL:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
    var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()['assets']);
    result = $.param(decodedUrl, true);

    console.log(result);

});
```

But i am totally unsure how to get the `AssetId` oder `DerivateiveId` from my result var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, In your url the querystring is 'asset' and you are trying to get value of assets.

Then when you get value of asset it's a string, you can parse it to json using JSON.parse. This will give you an array of object. From that you can fetch whatever you need.

```
var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()['asset']);
     var result = JSON.parse(decodedUrl);
     console.log('AssetId==>'+result[0].AssetId);
     console.log('DerivativeId==>'+result[0].DerivativeId);
```

Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/f3ny7j8c/6/).

Answer (score 0):

check out [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) to get the parameter out of the url. After that you can use JSON.parse(param) to parse that url parameter string into a json object.

Answer (score 0):

The URL i got after using decodeURIComponent() is different than the URL in your link.
I am unsure how to modify it to my needs.